# AJAX toolkit Tabcontainer First tab visible always

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

I am using AJAX toolkit TabContainer control to display 4 tabs in asp.net page. I have problem with this control that First tab is visible always when i click on any other tab.
Anybody have solution for this problem?
  Code is :

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer runat="server" ID="TabContainData" ActiveTabIndex="0">
                            <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" ID="tabCreateData">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    Create Data
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <table>
                                        Table Content here                                       
                                    </table>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
                            <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" ID="tabDataAssign">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    Assignment of data
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <table>
                                        Table Content here
                                    </table>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
                            <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" ID="tabDataTask">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    Data Task
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <table>
                                        Table Content here
                                    </table>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
                            <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" ID="tabReviewData">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    Review Data
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <table>
                                        Table Content here
                                    </table>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
                        </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

Comment: If there is any, could you post the code behind ?